# Match the path of a URL, minus the filename extension

Tags: regex, nginx

What would be the best regular expression for this scenario?

Given this URL:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
```

How should I go about selecting everything between (but not including) `http://php.net` and `.php`:

```
/manual/en/function.preg-match
```

This is for an [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) configuration file.

Comment: `(?:http:[\/]{2}.+?[.])[^\/]+(.+)[.]+.+`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=net).*(?=\.php)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Explanation:

```
"
(?<=      # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   net       # Match the characters “net” literally
)
.         # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?=       # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   \.        # Match the character “.” literally
   php       # Match the characters “php” literally
)
"
```

Comment: Thanks FailedDev for the detail explanation, that work perfectly

Comment: `'/net(.*)\.php/'`, simpler, shorter (and possibly better performing) version of the same expression. (I prefer expressions without wastefully unnecessary lookarounds.)

Answer (score 20):

A regular expression might not be the most effective tool for this job.

Try using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), combined with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$url      = 'http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php';
$path     = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathinfo = pathinfo($path);

echo $pathinfo['dirname'], '/', $pathinfo['filename'];
```

The above code outputs:

```
/manual/en/function.preg-match
```

Comment: Thanks phoenix, that works too, but i was looking for a reg ex solution for this.

Comment: @silkAdmin That's curious; why must the solution be a regular expression?

Comment: Sorry i shouldn't have used the PHP tag that was confusing, i needed the regex for an Nginx config file where your solution is not an option

Comment: Ajá.  Thanks for the info; I went ahead and updated your question to make it clearer for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/net(.*)\.php$/","http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php", $matches);
echo $matches[1];
// prints /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use a regular expression to dissect a URL. PHP has built-in functions for this, [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) and [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/parse_url).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, here are two ways that have not been explored:

```
substr($url, strpos($s, '/', 8), -4)
```

Or:

```
substr($s, strpos($s, '/', 8), -strlen($s) + strrpos($s, '.'))
```

Based on the idea that HTTP schemes `http://` and `https://` are at most 8 characters, so typically it suffices to find the first slash from the 9th position onwards. If the extension is always `.php` the first code will work, otherwise the other one is required.

For a pure regular expression solution you can break the string down like this:

```
~^(?:[^:/?#]+:)?(?://[^/?#]*)?([^?#]*)~
                              ^
```

The path portion would be inside the first memory group (i.e. index 1), indicated by the `^` in the line underneath the expression. Removing the extension can be done using `pathinfo()`:

```
$parts = pathinfo($matches[1]);
echo $parts['dirname'] . '/' . $parts['filename'];
```

You can also tweak the expression to this:

```
([^?#]*?)(?:\.[^?#]*)?(?:\?|$)
```

This expression is not very optimal though, because it has some back tracking in it. In the end I would go for something less custom:

```
$parts = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo $parts['dirname'] . '/' . $parts['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This general URL match allows you to select parts of a URL:

```
if (preg_match('/\\b(?P<protocol>https?|ftp):\/\/(?P<domain>[-A-Z0-9.]+)(?P<file>\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(?P<parameters>\\?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs['file'];
    //or you can append the $regs['parameters'] too
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution better than what most have provided so far, if you ask me: http://regex101.com/r/nQ8rH5

```
/http:\/\/[^\/]+\K.*(?=\.[^.]+$)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$url = "http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php";
preg_match("/http:\/\/php\.net(.+)\.php/", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

`$matches[0]` is your full URL, `$matches[1]` is the part you want.

See yourself: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hHmwI2

Answer (score 0):

## |(?<=\w)/.+(?=\.\w+$)|

- select everything from the first literal '/' preceded by
- look behind a Word(\w) character
- until followed by a look ahead

  - literal '.' appended by
  - one or more Word(\w) characters
  - before the end $

```
  re> |(?<=\w)/.+(?=\.\w+$)|
Compile time 0.0011 milliseconds
Memory allocation (code space): 32
  Study time 0.0002 milliseconds
Capturing subpattern count = 0
No options
First char = '/'
No need char
Max lookbehind = 1
Subject length lower bound = 2
No set of starting bytes
data> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
Execute time 0.0007 milliseconds
 0: /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

## |//[^/]*(.*)\.\w+$|

- find two literal '//' followed by anything but a literal '/'
- select everything until
- find literal '.' followed by only Word \w characters before the end $

```
  re> |//[^/]*(.*)\.\w+$|
Compile time 0.0010 milliseconds
Memory allocation (code space): 28
  Study time 0.0002 milliseconds
Capturing subpattern count = 1
No options
First char = '/'
Need char = '.'
Subject length lower bound = 4
No set of starting bytes
data> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
Execute time 0.0005 milliseconds
 0: //php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
 1: /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

## |/[^/]+(.*)\.|

- find literal '/' followed by at least 1 or more non literal '/'
- aggressive select everything before the last literal '.'

```
  re> |/[^/]+(.*)\.|
Compile time 0.0008 milliseconds
Memory allocation (code space): 23
  Study time 0.0002 milliseconds
Capturing subpattern count = 1
No options
First char = '/'
Need char = '.'
Subject length lower bound = 3
No set of starting bytes
data> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
Execute time 0.0005 milliseconds
 0: /php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.
 1: /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

## |/[^/]+\K.*(?=\.)|

- find literal '/' followed by at least 1 or more non literal '/'
- Reset select start \K
- aggressive select everything before
- look ahead last literal '.'

```
  re> |/[^/]+\K.*(?=\.)|
Compile time 0.0009 milliseconds
Memory allocation (code space): 22
  Study time 0.0002 milliseconds
Capturing subpattern count = 0
No options
First char = '/'
No need char
Subject length lower bound = 2
No set of starting bytes
data> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
Execute time 0.0005 milliseconds
 0: /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

## |\w+\K/.*(?=\.)|

- find one or more Word(\w) characters before a literal '/'
- reset select start \K
- select literal '/' followed by
- anything before
- look ahead last literal '.'

```
  re> |\w+\K/.*(?=\.)|
Compile time 0.0009 milliseconds
Memory allocation (code space): 22
  Study time 0.0003 milliseconds
Capturing subpattern count = 0
No options
No first char
Need char = '/'
Subject length lower bound = 2
Starting byte set: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P 
  Q R S T U V W X Y Z _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
data> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
Execute time 0.0011 milliseconds
 0: /manual/en/function.preg-match
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression for matching everything after "net" and before ".php":

```
$pattern = "net([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\.php";
```

In the above regular expression, you can find the matching group of characters enclosed by "()" to be what you are looking for.

Hope it's useful.

Comment: That will not match the given example, because there is a dot in it: `function.preg-match`

Comment: Not to mention it doesn't match slashes, either.  Also, the regexp is not anchored — which probably won't cause problems (the `*` operator is greedy by default), but it's not a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

`http:[\/]{2}.+?[.][^\/]+(.+)[.].+`

let's see, what it done:

`http:[\/]{2}.+?[.][^\/]` - non-capture group for `http://php.net`

`(.+)[.]` - capture part until last dot occur: `/manual/en/function.preg-match`

`[.].+`  - matching extension of file like this: `.php`